# Is Error Considered an Emission from an Observable in RxJs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

Quick question: Will `.do()` fire off when there is an error? The docs say, "Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but return an Observable that is identical to the source." Is an error considered an emission, too?

```
return this.authHttp.get(url)
      .delay(5000)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .do(() => console.log("I'm doing something"))
      .share()
      .catch(error => {
        if (isDev) this.toastr.error("The panels could not be retrieved from the API.");
        return this.handleEerror(error);
      });
```

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. I didn't think to shut off the API to cause an error until I had already posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.do()` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md#rxobservableprototypedoobserver--onnext-onerror-oncompleted) can take an optional `onError` callback for handling errors:

```
observable
  .do(
    value => console.log("I'm doing something"),
    err   => console.error('I got an error', err.stack)
  )
```

...otherwise it will just pass through the pipeline.

Comment: You mean, I should read the function signature and not just the comments? lol

Thanks for improving my answer!

Answer (score 0):

No.

In fact, everything in the pipeline is skipped until catch.